# Google Chart - date type

Tags: google-visualization

I'm trying to test the Google Chart, but I receive follow error:

`One or more participants failed to draw().
The filter cannot operate on a column of type string. Column type must be one of: number, date, datetime or timeofday. Column role must be domain, and correlate to a continuous axis.`

What am I doing wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

          google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['controls']});
          google.setOnLoadCallback(drawDashboard);

      function drawDashboard() {
    var obj = [["Date","buy","sell"],["Date(2012,10,2)",15,14],["Date(2012,10,3)",55,51],["Date(2012,10,4)",53,49]];
        var dataa = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(obj);
        var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard_div'));

        var donutRangeSlider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
          'controlType': 'ChartRangeFilter',
          'containerId': 'filter_div',
          'options': {
              'filterColumnIndex': 0,
              'ui': {
                     'chartType': 'LineChart',
                     'chartOptions': {
                       'chartArea': {'width': '90%'},
                       'hAxis': {'baselineColor': 'none'}
                     },
                     'chartView': { 'columns': [0, 1] },
                     'minRangeSize': 86400000
                }
          },
        });

        var lineChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
          'chartType': 'LineChart',
          'containerId': 'chart_div',
          'options': {
                title: 'Title',
          }
        });

        dashboard.bind(donutRangeSlider, lineChart);
        dashboard.draw(dataa);
      }       
</script>
```

Comment: You can find answer to this question at Google Visualization API forum [Google Chart - date type.](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-visualization-api/tEXK99ADYwM)

Answer (score 1):

arrayToDataTable does not support date or time values as mentioned here: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datatables_dataviews#arraytodatatable

> #### arrayToDataTable()
>
> This helper function creates and populates a DataTable using a single call.
>
> **Advantages:**
> Very simple and readable code executed in the browser.
>
> **Disadvantages:**
> You cannot explicitly specify the data type of each column; the type is inferred from the data passed in.
>  You cannot use any date or time values in your data.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
 var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
    data.addColumn('number', 'buy');
    data.addColumn('number', 'sell');
    data.addRows([
    [new Date(2012,10,2),15,14],
    [new Date(2012,10,3),55,51],
    [new Date(2012,10,4)",53,49]
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably mess up with the java-script, I have taken data from your code and created sample html page in [Google Code Playground](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#line_chart).

Check the following code it display visual chart without any error:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>
      Google Visualization API Sample
    </title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function drawVisualization() {
        // Create and populate the data table.
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([["Date","buy","sell"],["Date(2012,10,2)",15,14],["Date(2012,10,3)",55,51],["Date(2012,10,4)",53,49]]);


        // Create and draw the visualization.
        new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
            draw(data, {curveType: "function",
                        width: 500, height: 400,
                        vAxis: {maxValue: 10}}
                );
      }


      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
    <div id="visualization" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The problem still exist in your example. The Google chart recognize "Date(2012,10,2)" as string but must be data type. Please see https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/dev/implementing_data_source?hl=pt-BR#jsondatatable

Answer (score 0):

arrayToDataTable does support Date value now (not sure about 3 years ago)

In your code, do this instead

```
var obj = [[{label: "Date", type: "date"},"buy","sell"],[new Date(2012,10,2),15,14],[new Date(2012,10,3),55,51],[new Date(2012,10,4),53,49]];
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(obj);
```

Remember that current timezone is applied when you call new Date(...), maybe you want to make some more adjustment.